# Docker client not able to connect to docker host on VM on Windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using Docker Toolbox 1.8.2 and it is working fine on my OSX. On Windows, I have some problems.

I have created a new "default" VM (virtualbox), then connected my docker client to this docker host using "eval $(docker-machine env default)" on Cygwin. When I try to run "docker ps" from Cygwin, I get the following error:

```
Get http://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.20/containers/json: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: 
ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made because the target machine
actively refused it..
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

If I SSH into that machine and execute "docker ps", then it will return that no containers are running, meaning that the host is running.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had some problems with bash (mingw) on Windows 10 myself. Solved by creating a Docker VM with "docker-machine.exe" using PowerShell.

Comment: Try workaround from this post, it helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641003/error-checking-tls-connection-error-checking-and-or-regenerating-the-certs/34646333#34646333

Answer (score 1):

Prereqs:

Make sure you have brew installed.
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

if your having troubles using brew, try uninstalling it. Then try re-installing it. To uninstall it try to use...
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

Install Docker

**brew install docker**

Install Docker-Machine

**brew install docker-machine**

Create New docker Machine host - just use virtual box

**docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default**

Set you environment variable to see docker-machine - you should set this in your .bashrc file.

**eval $(docker-machine env default)**

Comment: "I am using Docker Toolbox 1.8.2 and it is working fine on my OSX." Did you even read OP's post?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Windows, but OS X, but in my case such error means that he cannot find route to virtual host.

In my case 
`sudo route -nv add -net 192.168.59 -interface vboxnet1`
helps.

Change it into Windows command and try out (of course you may have to change interface name or part of IP).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because docker daemon is not yet running.

On Windows, using boot2docker this is how it worked for me

- make sure your VM is running, run `docker-machine ls` to list all VMs
- boot2docker init
- boot2docker start
- eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"

Comment: The Docker daemon is running, because I can ssh to the VM and type "docker ps" and it will work. I just can't do it from my Windows machine.