# How can I save my RSA KEY in my Docker Machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

`~/.ssh/my_id_rsa` in a VM created by `docker-machine create` gets disappeared whenever I restart it. I've read documents on docs.docker.com, but I couldn't find information about this issue.

My host machine is Mac (El Capitan), and the version of docker-machine is as follows:

```
$ docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

I've created my VM with following options:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
```

Is there any advice on how to fix this issue? Where should I look into?

### More concretely, I want to know how to avoid this issue:

```
(host) $ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
(host) $ docker-machine ssh dev
(dev) $ ssh-keygen
...
(dev) $ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys   authorized_keys2  id_rsa            id_rsa.pub
(dev) $ logout
(host) $ docker-machine restart dev
(host) $ docker-machine ssh dev
(dev) $ ls ~/.ssh
authorized_keys   authorized_keys2
```

Where's "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, I don't specify anything regarding ssh keys: `docker-machine` creates a passphrase-less ssh key in `~/.docker/machine/machines/<amachine>/`

If you want to specify your own, see [this example from the `docker-machine` documentation](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/docs/drivers/generic.md#example):

```
$ docker-machine create \
  --driver generic \
  --generic-ip-address=203.0.113.81 \
  --generic-ssh-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  vm
```

The OP adds:

```
(dev) $ logout
(host) $ docker-machine restart dev
(host) $ docker-machine ssh dev
```

That is creating ssh key within the virtual machine itself: the TinyCore-based boot2docker only persists what is in /var/lib/boot2docker, nothing else.
It does mount `/Users`, but other than that, anything else (including `/home/docker`, the `~` in `~/.ssh`)is reset to the `boot2docker.iso` original content at the next restart.
See "[boot2docker: Persist data](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#persist-data)"

For those ssh keys to persists across session, you would need to either:

- generate them in /Users/any/path/you/want (as they would actually be stored on the host)
- or generate them in `/var/lib/boot2docker`

Comment: I understand you don't want to specify your key. I am just saying your key should not be involved at all by a docker-machine create command, as docker-machine manages its own set of keys.

Comment: Hmm, ok. It makes sense. But do you know the reason why "docker-machine restart" deletes my key? (I've added "More concretely..." section to the question)

Comment: @aeas44 I just read your "more concretely" section of your question, and I have edited my answer accordingly. Generating your ssh key *within* the VM is something I had missed initially.

Comment: Thx @VonC! I didn't know that data in boot2docker is basically ephemeral except for things in /var/lib/boot2docker. It's exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: @aeas44 Yes, I use /var/lib/boot2docker to put scripts I want to persists, like one setting a fixed IP address for the machine at each reboot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36130098/6309